# Try To Access File(choose file) Flutter InApp Webview and ended crash

Tags: flutter, webview, permissions

So i want to make a webview flutter that can use camera and file access(before i use inapp i use webview pro to access file but it cant access camera and the inApp is the opposite it)

the crash

```
F/crashpad(13326): -----BEGIN CRASHPAD MINIDUMP-----
F/crashpad(13326): )iyJL')EstLw({7fR7?G4R;*tjf<|z`{])P^:TpSyjpq&W2kpq&W2kz&R)r9#_iBrtuE|8Sw(mBHulBf^aF06D/igvzFYVxsKwGV.DJHe4$mlKMiLs<l/!g!u+p68aw]/w(\{n5wm90ZKt:(U6L:ZL\3!!/#!CF!GPS!9=gv6/*"E?qt;<:>oOXLhD.;&!0U;!-!cIvP1@ne0/P!F<VD;b-!fyi1axk[dZ8}5w]J;!+$iay7||"!Py,757)Mpb!MiM`XQ+d}Kt`a?l@W9r!6y5`64=QjhW</&F]?Uj<v,-~]h.^D:@eJK7!Wn-VID=f4Wln|?W/yrya"Vx47V<6{EB_.:932P7zotIxiOX6wlGUq+=s/ECm6h(qe=T9C7&\8$F^{:9-_+lB;@\DZ"T__h{R4>=c{,DALs@kW?r@/"{42"TQD^WAk6:(WUfO+A^)Z%bGY5DcZO\v.R0:=8T}E-X/):mV&gSa4GTdJye4oZQG?P/DA!>W`lePj[$E:69%L
F/crashpad(13326): -----END CRASHPAD MINIDUMP-----
F/libc    (12540): Fatal signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x7dbef21a50 in tid 12540 (m.example.inapp), pid 12540 (m.example.inapp)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Redmi/joyeuse_id/joyeuse:11/RKQ1.200826.002/V12.5.4.0.RJZIDXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2023-09-21 14:01:52+0700
pid: 12540, tid: 12540, name: m.example.inapp  >>> com.example.inapp <<<
uid: 10444
signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code 1 (TRAP_BRKPT), fault addr 0x7dbef21a50
Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(289)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000000400  x2  ffffffffffffffff  x3  ffffffffffffffff    
    x4  0000000000000058  x5  0000007ea2a61000  x6  0000007ea2a61000  x7  000000000044466a    
    x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000000    
    x12 0000007fd4364b00  x13 0000000000000051  x14 0000007e9c3c4be2  x15 ffffffffffffffff    
    x16 0000007dc4d1e588  x17 0000007e9c3b583c  x18 0000007ea20a0000  x19 0000007fd4366418    
    x20 0000007fd4366428  x21 0000007fd4366430  x22 0000007dc4dd4d30  x23 0000007dc4dd4d50    
    x24 0000007dc4d45000  x25 0000000000000050  x26 0000007ea18fa000  x27 00000002000c7620    
    x28 0000000000000050  x29 0000007fd43663b0
    lr  0000007dbef21194  sp  0000007fd4365dc0  pc  0000007dbef21a50  pst 0000000060001000    
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000003112a50  /data/app/~~ZZzwNU0YlN6LFAvQ3p3Mmg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_584517233-vO43LKLhIXfbtnrtrJCRqg==/base.apk!libmonochrome_64.so (offset 0x8ba000) (BuildId: 
d3aad27260eff1fa6d833bd74ff3f3bc
```

i've try to handle permission with permission handler package

```
`import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Permission.camera.request();
  await Permission.microphone.request();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

 //on the inapp class also i add this
          crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
            javaScriptEnabled: true,
            allowFileAccessFromFileURLs: true,
            mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false
          ),

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _requestPermissions();
  }
```

also i added on the android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

im pretty sure nothing wrong with the web cause when i try one by one(package) for the feature its work on them